# Local links in a fancybox div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hidden `div` for Fancybox (v2) usage:

```
<div id="embargomsg" style="display:none">
    <h1 class="entry-title">You Can't Use That Yet</h1>
    <p>That's the special stuff.</p>
    <h2 class="pitch">New to the Site?</h2>
    <p class="pitch"><a class="button secondary promo" href="/register" target="_top"><span>Get Started Today</span></a></p>
    <h2 class="pitch">Already Registered?</h2>
    <p class="pitch"><a class="button secondary action" href="/login" target="_top"><span>Log In</span></a></p>
</div><!-- #embargomsg -->
```

Various links elsewhere in the page with a class of `authctrl` should open the fancybox...

```
<a class="authctrl" href="/specialstuff1">Special Stuff</a>
<a class="authctrl" href="/specialstuff2">Some Other Special Stuff</a>
```

... using this function:

```
$('.authctrl').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#embargomsg').fancybox({
    closeClick : false
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

... but when either of the `.authctrl` links are clicked, the Fancybox seems to just quickly close and reopen. I tried adding `closeClick: false` to no avail.

Comment: this would end in a loop, wouldnt it? You can define the fancybox outside of the click function

Comment: Am I mistakenly thinking I had to apply `.trigger('click')` to get the fancybox open when an `.authctrl` element is clicked?

Comment: not directly, but what does the html of embargomsg look like? Fancybox shall only be called on elements with an url in them, like <a>. If it is supposed to show html content, you have to do it otherwise. But its not clear from within your question...

Comment: You could also make it like so `.click();` to trigger a click to open the fancybox, its shorter ;)

Comment: html for #embargomsg added

Comment: just look up how to load particular content with fancybox. i believe its the content property :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `$('#embargomsg')` have an href?

```
$('.authctrl').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#embargomsg').trigger('click');
});

$('#embargomsg').fancybox({
    closeClick : false
});
```

provide some markup please.

Comment: Revised the description for clarity. Hope that helps!

Comment: Because I didn't want to reference #embargomsg in the (many various) trigger elements, I ended up doing `fancybox.open` this way: `$.fancybox.open( [{ href : '#embargomsg'}], { closeClick : false });` I would post a link to my research but this was cobbled together from a couple of other questions that were trying to solve problems that were very unrelated.